# Sum cell values below until a blank cell with Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am looking for a Python code that enables me to sum all the values within a column (e.g. Column A) until a blank cell is reached. This process should then repeat itself until the end of the column.

I managed to use an array formula in Excel to do this, with my desired output in Column B:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 33 |
| 10 |  |
| 11 |  |
| 12 |  |
|  | 41 |
| 15 |  |
| 12 |  |
| 14 |  |
|  | 122 |
| 20 |  |
| 22 |  |
| 40 |  |
| 40 |  |

I used the following formula for Excel: =IF(A2="",SUM(A2:INDEX($A2:A$1000,MATCH(TRUE,($A3:A$1000=""),0))),"") and then filled the formula down to cover the cells below.

However, I am having difficulty getting the same results in Python. I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve this.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried,?

Comment: blank means NaN or `''`(empty string) in pandas dataframe? Please also provide the code that generates your input as a DataFrame, since it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

blank is null

```
import pandas as pd
data = [None, 10, 11, 12, None, 15, 12, 14, None, 20, 22, 40, 40]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A'])
```

df

```
    A
0   NaN
1   10.0
2   11.0
3   12.0
4   NaN
5   15.0
6   12.0
7   14.0
8   NaN
9   20.0
10  22.0
11  40.0
12  40.0
```

---

**Code**

```
cond = df['A'].isna()
grp = cond.cumsum()
df.loc[cond, 'B'] = df.groupby(grp)['A'].sum().tolist()
```

df

```
    A       B
0   NaN     33.0
1   10.0    NaN
2   11.0    NaN
3   12.0    NaN
4   NaN     41.0
5   15.0    NaN
6   12.0    NaN
7   14.0    NaN
8   NaN     122.0
9   20.0    NaN
10  22.0    NaN
11  40.0    NaN
12  40.0    NaN
```

The blanks in column B appear to be null, so I coded them as null. If the blanks are empty strings, use following code(edit by mozway comment):

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
cond = s.isna()
df.loc[cond, 'B'] = s.groupby(cond.cumsum()).sum().tolist()
```

Comment: I think you have to replace empty strings with NaN also for the summation, else you won't be able to sum numbers and empty strings. Alternatively, use `df.loc[~cond, 'A'].groupby(grp).sum().tolist()` ;)

Comment: @mozway I see. I need to revise the groupby code due to the sum issue.

Comment: Or just start by replacing the `''` by `NaN` like I did and your code should work as is. Or maybe better `df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')` then we're safe that the values are only numeric and whatever other things are NaN ;)

Comment: @mozway `to_numeric` is good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a custom group with [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)+[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
# identify empty cells
m = df['A'].isna()

# compute the sum
df['B'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum())['A'].transform('sum').where(m)
```

Note that this assumes that the empty cells are NaN and the numbers integers/floats. If you have strings you first need to convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
# if blank cells are empty string, or numbers are strings
# convert to numeric
# you can do this step in any case, it won't hurt
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
       A      B
0    NaN   33.0
1   10.0    NaN
2   11.0    NaN
3   12.0    NaN
4    NaN   41.0
5   15.0    NaN
6   12.0    NaN
7   14.0    NaN
8    NaN  122.0
9   20.0    NaN
10  22.0    NaN
11  40.0    NaN
12  40.0    NaN
```

Used input:

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [nan, 10, 11, 12, nan, 15, 12, 14, nan, 20, 22, 40, 40]})
```

Intermediates:

```
       A      B      m  m.cumsum()    sum
0    NaN   33.0   True           1   33.0
1   10.0    NaN  False           1   33.0
2   11.0    NaN  False           1   33.0
3   12.0    NaN  False           1   33.0
4    NaN   41.0   True           2   41.0
5   15.0    NaN  False           2   41.0
6   12.0    NaN  False           2   41.0
7   14.0    NaN  False           2   41.0
8    NaN  122.0   True           3  122.0
9   20.0    NaN  False           3  122.0
10  22.0    NaN  False           3  122.0
11  40.0    NaN  False           3  122.0
12  40.0    NaN  False           3  122.0
```